# Kivy Apple mach-o-Linker Error happened

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have problems.
I using kivy for ios.
and i tried build with Xcode through kivy for iOS toolchains.
Then Error's happened.

I think these errors are a problem with "LibSDL2_Mixer".
However, in my "toolschain status" sdl2_mixer has been successfully built.

Another yellow error,
 "directory not found for option '-F / Users / user / Documents / Kivy / kivy-ios / dist / frameworks'"
 will also disappear if I erase FrameworkSearch Path in BuildSetting.
(Actually I do not know if this is correct.)

However, the problem is a serious red error.

I will describe my version below.

- Python 2.7.14
- Cython 0.26.1
- OS HighSierra 10.13.1
- Kivy 1.10.0

I'm sorry that couldn't added raw image.
I have no 10 reputation, so i wrote link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oYEp.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUgzD.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRnAd.png

Comment: "an error" is the worst of all error, nobody can give any help for unspecific errors. Please add a proper error description!

Comment: Sorry, I will rewrite.

Comment: I edited my question :)

Comment: This is helped me!!
I  just added -lc++ to the Project (Not Target) Build Settings > Other Linker Flags
https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-firestack/issues/59